# Generate list of R plotly plots and pass it to subplot

Tags: r, plotly

I usually generate subplots in a for loop when using base R graphics (using `par(mfrow=c(nr,nc))`). I'm trying to do something similar with `plotly`, by generating a series of plots and saving them to a list to be later passed to the `subplot` function. However, for reasons that I don't understand, at the end of the loop all the elements of the list seem to contain the same plot (the last one). If I print each plot in the list within the loop (uncommenting the line starting with `print` in the example below), then the plots seem fine). I don't really understand what's going on. Could someone explain this unexpected behavior or point out issues with my example code below?

```
library(plotly)
plotList = list()
plotListNames = c("p1", "p2", "p3")

for (i in 1:3){
    x = rnorm(10)
    y = rnorm(10)
    thisName = plotListNames[i]
    plotList[[thisName]] = plot_ly(x=x,y=y, name=thisName)
    ##print(plotList[[thisName]]
}

sbp = subplot(plotList[["p1"]], plotList[["p2"]], plotList[["p3"]])
print(sbp)
```

Comment: try by adding evalate=TRUE in plotList[[thisName]] = plot_ly(x=x,y=y, name=thisName, evaluate=TRUE)

Comment: when I pass `evaluate=TRUE` I get an error: `Error in UseMethod("plotly_build") : 
  no applicable method for 'plotly_build' applied to an object of class "list"`

Comment: the issue with `evaluate` may be related to this: http://community.plot.ly/t/evaluate-broken-in-recent-versions-of-r-api/1060

Comment: it was working for me. I am using plotly_3.4.13

Comment: thanks, I can confirm that using `evaluate=TRUE` the plots work as expected with version 3.4.13. Using the latest version on CRAN (v3.6.0) results in an error when `evaluate=TRUE`, and using the master branch on github, although does not result in an error when `evaluate=TRUE` does not produce the expected plots.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
plotList[[thisName]] =  plotly_build(plot_ly(x=x,y=y, name=thisName))
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.